# StructureMap with MVC and multiple layers

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am using StructureMap.MVC5 and have the following projects and classes:

```
Web
    HomeController(PageService pageService)
Services
    PageService(IPageRepository pageRepository)
Repositories
    PageRepository : IPageRepository
IRepositories
    IPageRepository
```

With the default implementation of StructureMap.MVC5 it automatically resolves the PageService into my HomeController, but not PageRepository into my PageService. This gives me the exception: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

This is solved by adding a line to DefaultRegistry:

```
For<IPageRepository>().Use<PageRepository>();
```

But obviously I would rather have StructureMap automatically resolve this. Is there a way to achieve that?

This is what the DefaultRegistry looks like:

```
public DefaultRegistry()
{
    Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your repository isn't being resolved automatically is because it's in another assembly, where as your service is being referenced within your controller, meaning it gets resolved by the `TheCallingAssembly` call.

To tell StructureMap to load your repositories you have to explicitly tell it which assembly to scan:

```
scan.AssemblyContainingType<IPageRepository>();
```

The type specified doesn't have to be a `IPageRepository` type, just some type within your repository assembly so StructureMap knows where to look.

Now any types within your repository assembly should be resolved automatically.